# How to find whether the user account is builtin or manually created?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, user-accounts, administrator

I'm working on a project using user accounts in the computer.  I can find all the administrator users in the computer using `NetLocalGroupGetMembers()`.  But I also want to find whether an administrator account is a built-in account (created at the time of installation) or created manually (by user).  I am using C++, and I am wondering if there is any Win32 API to find this, or any other way?

Comment: Maybe from SID structure? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-sid and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-lookupaccountsidw

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! But we cannot use SID structure determining that,I tried to compare both the structure ,they are same only the final number is different(we cannot use it for differentiating).

Comment: exist well known user rids - from `DOMAIN_USER_RID_ADMIN` (500) up to `DOMAIN_USER_RID_MAX`(999). so called created manually (by user) have rid > 1000. so called *defaultuser0* have rid 1000

Comment: [*you can verify that the last number (the RID) is greater than or equal to 1000.*](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20141212-00/?p=43413)

Comment: @hacker You can post an answer to end this thread:)